# Clicking the button in grid format in selenium webdriver

Tags: selenium-webdriver

how to code for clicking a button in grid format in selenium webdriver, the code is showing error when done by xpath, classname.click ??

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
selenium.clickAt("//button[@id='blabla']","");
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to locate the button first (you can use xpath) then click on the element found.

Example (ruby code)

```
driver.find_element(:xpath, '//xpath-here').click
```